# Facelets: new location for "xmlns:h" and "xmlns:f"?

Tags: jsf, facelets, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to use some xml name spaces here,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
              xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
              xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                >
```

but since Oracle've eaten Java, the http://java.sun.com/jsf/* links are broken now (thank you Oracle).

Anybody knows their new locations? Or which maven dependency solves that (com.sun.facelets.jsf-facelets, javax.faces.jsf-api, javax.faces.jsf-impl don't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter that they are broken. These are just identifiers and no links (though they look like links).

If your page doesn't work, it's rather a problem of missing libraries.

Replacing "Sun" with "Oracle" won't work either ;-)

Comment: oh... I wonder, which maven dependency would solve that, because com.sun.facelets.jsf-facelets, javax.faces.jsf-api, javax.faces.jsf-impl don't solve that...

Comment: @Andrey: I don't do Maven, so not sure what's the right way, but you can find some Maven dependency examples here http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

Comment: @BalusC: Ok, thanks! I just killed 10 hours trying to make jsf+SpringMVC run on Tomcat6. With no result. I guess I shuold try JBoss with webflow...